# encountering an SMTP script issue when using variables

Tags: bash, email, variables, smtp

[image: Seems like i cant use the variable in bash after i netcat in, any solution? It all works when i dont use variables. This is for a quick email spoofer for class]

Seems like i cant use the variable in bash after i netcat in, any solution? It all works when i dont use variables. This is for a quick email spoofer for class. I do have #!bin/bash at the top too.

Comment: Please interchange the image with your entire script. You can/should use the script tags to raise readability. :)

Answer (score 1):

```
add = 'mailserver'
```

VS.

```
add='mailserver'
```

Always make sure that [no spaces exist between the variable name and the value to be assigned](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/newbie_traps#setting_variables).